# Sorting and sequencing data from a file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I've developed a program that stores a list of ids, so:

[image]

But for the desired purposes, the data should take the sequential form, so that the first pair of ids is something like: "889926212541448192" becomes 1 and "889919950248448000" becomes 2. That is, the file to be should be something like:

[image]

Where the first id connects with 2,3 and 6, and the id 4 only with 5, forming a network.
I have no experience in this area, but I can not find a way to do this reading.
I tried to do some programs, but they only read row and not column id to id. This data is saved following the following program

```
import json

arq = open('ids.csv','w')
arq.write('Source'+','+'Target')
arq.write("\n")

lista_rede = [] #list to store all ids

with open('dados_twitter.json', 'r') as f:

    for line in f:
        lista = []

        tweet = json.loads(line) # to write as a Python dictionary
        lista = list(tweet.keys()) #write list of keys

        try:
            if 'retweeted_status' in lista:
                id_rt = json.dumps(tweet['retweeted_status']['id_str'])
                id_status = json.dumps(tweet['id_str'])

                lista_rede.append(tweet['id_str'])
                lista_rede.append(tweet['retweeted_status']['id_str'])

                arq.write( id_status +','+ id_rt )
                arq.write("\n")

            if tweet['quoted_status'] in lista :
                id_rt = json.dumps(tweet['quoted_status']['id_str'])
                id_status = json.dumps(tweet['id_str'])

                lista_rede.append(tweet['id_str'])
                lista_rede.append(tweet['quoted_status']['id_str'])

                arq.write( id_status +','+ id_rt )
                arq.write("\n")
        except:
               continue
arq.close()
```

As a result I have a file with ids data in pairs of interactions.
How can I then rearrange these data in reading, or even how to write them ?? In Python or another language?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet would do the job-

```
import re

header = ''
id_dict = {}

# read the ids
with open('ids.csv') as fr:
    header = fr.readline()
    for line in fr:
        ids = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\d+', line)]
        try:
            id_dict[int(ids[0])].append(int(ids[1]))
        except:
            id_dict[int(ids[0])] = [int(ids[1])]

# sort the ids
for key in id_dict:
    id_dict[key].sort()

# save the sorted ids in a new file
with open('ids_sorted.txt', 'w') as fw:
    # fw.write(header)
    for key in sorted(id_dict):
        for value in id_dict[key]:
            fw.write("{0} {1}\n".format(key, value))
```